# Building contour lines in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I need to plot a contour plot (similar to [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html)) according to the data from the text file. I'm building a coordinate grid. `Z` values are known only on the main diagonal. To find the values in the remaining points advised extrapolation. How do I extrapolate from the resulting grid?

Link to file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l4cEVo6SYunwnMNrIIjBPcIe3YxaGsKz

Here is a small snippet of code that helps to load this file into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf(r'D:\download\image2015010100.col2', skiprows=[1], na_values=[99999.9])
d = {
    'YYYY': 'year',
    'MM':'month',
    'DD':'day',
    'HH':'hour',
    'MM.1':'minute',
    'SS':'second',
    }
df = df.rename(columns=d)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, :6])
df = df.iloc[:, 6:]
```

This is how this DF looks like:

```
In [171]: df
Out[171]:
                      NAL X  NAL Y    NAL Z   LYR X   LYR Y    LYR Z   HOR X   HOR Y  ...     TAR Y    TAR Z  SUW X  SUW Y  SUW Z  BRZ X  BRZ Y  BRZ Z
2015-01-01 00:00:00  7154.0  781.9  54297.5  7388.6  1046.0  54320.9  7821.3  1002.6  ...    2479.3  49164.9 -125.4 -114.8  -61.0   18.9   62.6   45.0
2015-01-01 00:00:10  7155.7  782.4  54298.5  7388.3  1046.0  54321.1  7821.3  1002.6  ...    2479.2  49164.9 -125.3 -114.8  -61.0   19.0   62.4   45.0
2015-01-01 00:00:20  7154.3  783.4  54296.8  7388.6  1045.8  54321.1  7821.3  1002.4  ...    2479.1  49165.0 -125.3 -114.9  -61.0   19.0   62.4   45.0
2015-01-01 00:00:30  7153.8  781.9  54296.6  7388.4  1045.5  54321.1  7821.1  1002.2  ...    2479.1  49165.0 -125.3 -115.0  -61.1   19.1   62.3   45.0
2015-01-01 00:00:40  7153.5  782.0  54299.5  7388.4  1045.0  54320.9  7821.1  1001.9  ...    2478.9  49165.0 -125.3 -115.1  -61.1   19.1   62.2   45.0
...                     ...    ...      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...     ...  ...       ...      ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
2015-01-01 23:59:10  7133.9  768.5  54474.8  7326.1  1082.7  54537.2  7746.0  1058.9  ...    2513.5  49151.7 -127.4  -86.8  -65.4   16.8   94.5   36.3
2015-01-01 23:59:20  7134.1  767.0  54471.9  7328.1  1076.6  54535.9  7743.4  1050.7  ...    2513.4  49151.7 -127.5  -86.8  -65.4   16.8   94.5   36.3
2015-01-01 23:59:30  7133.6  766.0  54468.4  7328.5  1071.4  54534.2  7740.6  1044.8  ...    2513.4  49151.6 -127.6  -86.8  -65.4   16.8   94.4   36.3
2015-01-01 23:59:40  7134.1  763.6  54465.3  7328.4  1067.0  54532.5  7738.0  1040.4  ...    2513.3  49151.7 -127.7  -86.8  -65.4   16.7   94.3   36.3
2015-01-01 23:59:50  7133.1  763.8  54464.5  7327.3  1063.4  54530.6  7735.7  1038.0  ...    2513.4  49151.8 -127.7  -86.8  -65.4   16.5   94.4   36.3

[8640 rows x 102 columns]
```

Comment: Please read how to post a question. No one likes to look at a link into your google drive. If it's your data, simply post the data, if it's a plot, just add the picture here.

Comment: I'd recommend to provide a file with more data. This single row file can't be used for developing and testing solution...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l4cEVo6SYunwnMNrIIjBPcIe3YxaGsKz